# GET http://localhost/website/src/node_modules/three/build/three.module.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found) when importing THREE JS

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, npm

I am trying to get threejs to work.

I am using a XAMPP server with the current directory structure:

[image]

[image]

`.src/main.js` looks like this:

`import * as THREE from './node_modules/three/build/three.module.js';`

But I keep ge

When launching `index.html`, I seem to be getting this error: `GET http://localhost/website/src/node_modules/three/build/three.module.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: Please add project's package.json

Comment: Where does the request comes from?! `/src/node_modules/` does not exists.